# Velocity as a function of position, given velocity as a function of time

Tags: integration, physics, change-of-variable

Knowing the expression for the acceleration as a function of time:
$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = - c v^n$$
(for some constant c >0 and n >1), one needs to find the velocity as a function of time and as a function of position. Solving for the velocity as a function of time is pretty straightforward and has lead me to the following:
$$ v(t) = [ (n-1)ct + v_{O}^{(1-n)}]^{\frac{1}{1-n}} $$
Given the initial condition that $ v(0) = v_0$. Now, to find $v(x)$, I tried to use
$$ \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} = a(t) \frac{1}{v(t)} $$
This leads to
$$ \int \frac{dv}{v^n} = \int \frac{-c}{ [ (n-1)ct + v_{O}^{(1-n)}]^{\frac{1}{1-n}}} dx = -ct $$
Where the last equality is obtained from the first DE after separating variables.  I don't see how this could possibly give me $v(x)$. How could one change variables in the integral without being in the possession of a relationship between $t$ and $x$ (Or am I? Am I overseeing  something?), which if I had I could simply insert into the RHS of the equation, without having to worry about the integral at all.
Any push into the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Update: I solved it by considering the cases $n = 1, n = 2 $ and $ n>2$ separately, solving for t as a function of x and then simply substituting the result back into the original equation

Answer (score 2):

I want to emphasize that the '$t$' in the fourth equation should be treated as a function of $x$(displacement).

Let me just rewrite your third formula with a input $\tilde{x}$ (You probably have applied the inverse function theorem.) :
$$
\frac{dv}{dx} (\tilde{x})= \frac{dv}{dt}(\,t(\tilde{x})\,)\,\, \frac{dt}{dx} (\tilde{x}) = a( t(\tilde{x}) ) \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt} (t (\tilde{x}))} =  \frac{a( t(\tilde{x}) )}{v (t (\tilde{x}))} 
$$

, where $t(\tilde{x})$ is the inverse function of the time-displacement function.

This slightly different notation lets us understand the integral more precisely. Indeed, your integral is precisely
$$
\int_{v_0}^{v(\tilde{x})} \frac{dv}{v^n} = \int_{0}^{\tilde{x}} \frac{-c}{ [\, (n-1)c\,\,t(x) + v_{O}^{(1-n)}\,]^{\frac{1}{1-n}}} dx \quad \text{}.
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{1-n}  \left( v(\tilde{x})\,^{1-n} \,-\,v_0\,^{1-n} \right) = \mathrm{D}(\tilde{x}).
$$

( D is the result of our integral. (i.e our **Dream** function) )

Then our $v(x)$ can be derived as follows.
$$
v(x) = \left[ {v_0}^{1-n} - (n - 1)\, D(\tilde{x}) \right]^{1 / {1-n}}\, .
$$

Comment: Actually, I considered writing a bit more (for example, about the applicability of inverse function theorem, how to derive t(x), and the better method to calculate v(x) instead....), but I think this will be helpful enough.

Comment: If you can think of a shortcut to get $v(x)$, I would be happy if you could share it. Maybe something that outflanks the integral?

Comment: yeap, maybe deriving t(x) is unavoidable (integrate v(t) and calculate the inverse of it), but we can just substitue t(x) in the second equation for the goal. (This is the method what I thought)